# Mobile app publish (Google Play / App Store)

Tags: ios, google-play, app-store, app-store-connect

I’m really new in mobile app development, but I can make apps for android and ios. So my question is, Can I publish a free app that every one can download from the stores, but it can usable after a registration? So the initial state is a login/reg form. Every one can download, but just the approved users can use it. Can I publish this kind of app without any apple/android enterprise account? With the normal development account? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the normal developer account you should be able to publish this on Android.

For iOS, you'll have to provide a username and password, so that the app store review team can check it.

[image]

This can be found by clicking your app build in the **iOS App** subsection on the left hand side panel on **iTunes Connect**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the normal 99$ account is enough for the apple?

Comment: yes it would be :)